# django sort ManyToManyField by two fields

Tags: django

How do I sort by a M2M model for both a field with a value and another fields value.

The models are:

```
from django.db import models

class CalculatedValue(models.Model):
    Name     = models.CharField( max_length=200 )
    Value    = models.FloatField()

class MyModel(models.Model):
    Calculated_values = models.ManyToManyField( CalculatedValue )
```

An example is:

```
#first instance 
mdlOne = MyModel.objects.create()
topping = CalculatedValue.objects.create(Name='Cheese', Value=8. )
mdlOne.Calculated_values.add( topping )

favorite = CalculatedValue.objects.create(Name='Up Vote', Value=4. )
mdlOne.Calculated_values.add( favorite )

#second instance
mdlTwo = MyModel.objects.create()
anotherTopping = CalculatedValue.objects.create(Name='Cheese', Value=6. )
mdlTwo.Calculated_values.add( anotherTopping )
```

I want to sort MyModel by the cheese value.  In this example the query set would be (mdlTwo, mdlOne).

If I just wanted to sort by CalculatedValue Value, I could do this:

```
MyModel.objects.all().order_by(‘Calculated_values__Value’)
```

The above would sort by all values when I want the sorting to happen by Value where name=’Cheese’.  I’m not sure how to AND the name=’Cheese’.

Comment: Does this work? `MyModel.objects.filter(Calculated_values__Name="Cheese").order_by(‘Calculated_values__Value’)`

Comment: I thought about this but I didn’t think it would work.  My thought was that the filter results would return the same results as MyModel.objects.all() since all the instances have a CalculatedValue.  But when I tried it, it works for my use case.  I’ll have to dig into the sql to see why.

Comment: I think the reason is that if you `filter`, the `Calculated_values` with name not equal to `Cheese` would not be included on model `CalculatedValue` when django does the `join` behind the scene. But yea, do a `print <orm_statement>.query` and see if it's because of that.